For a given pair of positions in a family of winning sets, how many winning sets contain it?
This is a lot of exposition for what (I think) amounts to be a pretty simple combinatorics question.
It's about bounding the Max Pair-Degree from Beck's Combinatorial Games: Tic-Tac-Toe Theory. On page 27, in the section about $S$-building games, we have the following theorem:
Theorem: Let $(V, \mathcal{F})$ be a finite hypergraph: $V$ is an arbitrary finite set, and
$\mathcal{F}$ is an arbitrary family of subsets of $V$. The Maker–Breaker Game on $(V, \mathcal{F})$ is defined as follows: the two players, called Maker and Breaker, alternately occupy
previously unoccupied elements of “board” $V$ (the elements are called “points”); Maker’s goal is to occupy a whole “winning set” $A \in \mathcal{F}$, Breaker’s goal is to stop Maker. If $\mathcal{F}$ is $n$-uniform and $\frac{|\mathcal{F}|}{|V|}
> 2^{n−3}\Delta_2(\mathcal{F})$
where $\Delta_2(\mathcal{F})$ is the Max Pair-Degree, then Maker, as the first player, has a winning strategy in the Maker–Breaker Game on $(V, \mathcal{F})$.
The Max Pair-Degree is defined as follows: assume that, fixing any 2 distinct
points of board $V$, there are ≤ $\Delta_2(\mathcal{F})$ winning sets $A \in \mathcal{F}$ containing both points,
and equality occurs for some point pair. Then we call $\Delta_2(\mathcal{F})$ the Max Pair-Degree
of $\mathcal{F}.$
Later, Beck gives the following upper bound on the Max Pair-Degree, $\Delta_2(\mathcal{F})$: ${|A| \choose 2}$. (Or ${{k+1} \choose 2}$, as $(V, \mathcal{F})$ is $k$ uniform in the particular use-case).
I'm seeking clarification on where this upper bound comes from. My understanding is that it comes from the fact that for a given pair of points, they could play any of the ${|A| \choose 2}$ possible "roles" in a winning set $A$ (if we think of the points in any copy of $A$ as being labeled). I want to confirm that this understanding is correct.
